# Frequency change event - AudioKit & Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

I'm using Swift 4 with the AudioKit Framework 4.0.4.

I'd like to track the frequency of the input microphone of my iOS device in real time.

Currently I'm using a timer calling the output-function that prints out `oscillator.frequency` every 0.1 seconds.

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer( timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.output), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func output() {
   print("Frequency: \(oscillator.frequency)")
}
```

But is there a way to just listen for the change of the `oscillator.frequency` struct? Maybe something like an event called every time if the `oscillator.frequency` was changed.

Comment: is this question a duplicate to the linked answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234189/317461